# Sum of Two Squares product primality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fermat-numbers

[Euler's first proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) says that a number which is a STS, iff is divided by another **prime** STS, will give a quotient that is a STS. My question is, why is there a need for that primality? If I divide by a **composite** STS, will I still get a STS? I'm not the best in number theory but I sort of see it like this bear with me

$xy=STS$ where $x= prime STS$

STS can be made up of = non-STS * non-STS
OR
STS can be made up of = STS * STS

NON-STS made up of = non-STS * STS

Knowing that,

if I multiple a non-STS by a STS I will always have a non-STS left over, which in turns mean that that itself is not a STS. 
$xy (STS) = x (STS) * y (non-STS)$ is just not possible regardless of whether $x$ is a prime STS or not. If someone could help me out please. Thank you.

Comment: LucasCK I previously had an answer which on reflection was a bit complicated, and have now re-done it, see answer below.

Comment: $45=36+9=6^2+3^2$ and $5=4+1=2^2+1^2$ is prime but $45/5=9$ is not the sum of two squares unless we allow $9=3^2+0^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A natural number $m$ is a STS iff in its prime factorization each prime of the form $4k+3$ appears to an even power (possibly the $0$ power if that prime does not appear in the factorization). Now suppose $n=ab$ where $n$ is a STS, and assume also that $a$ is a STS. Then in the factorization of $n$ the $4k+3$ primeseach appear to even powers, and the assumption on $a$ gives that the factorization of it also contains each $4k+3$ prime to an even power. This forces even powers on the $4k+3$ primes in the factorization of $b,$ and so $b$ is also a STS.

I think maybe Euler's proposition was just trying to show the prime STS are primes in the ring of Gaussian integers.

Comment: that sums it up, thank you!

Comment: @LucasCK I just edited it to make the statement of when $m$ is STS more clear-- it is that each prime $4k+3$ appears in $m$ to an even power. [Previously there was a vague reference to the "number" of such primes, not quite correct.]